# C++ DLL floating-point determinism

Tags: c++, dll, floating-point

Can the same compilation of a C++ DLL exhibit different floating-point results on different machines?

We have some code in our DLL which performs a `<` comparison of two `double`s. For a particular set of inputs those `double`s are expected to be equal. Of course, the `<` comparison is dubious in this case, but what we didn't expect was to see different results from the comparison in our test versus the client's machine.

Comment: What's dubious? If you have `double a = foo(), b = a;`, then it is guaranteed that `a == b`...

Comment: I mean it's dubious in the sense that, while the two 'double's are expected to be equal, they are the result of quite different calculations and so in floating-point terms they are unlikely to be equal in the precise '==' sense.

Comment: I think you need to be a little clearer. **1st** you mention DLL which implies MS Windows, is that true, and which version? **2nd** by same compilation do you mean you copied the DLL from one machine to the other? **3rd** What compiler are you using?

Comment: @MikeLippert Yes, it's MS Windows XP (32 bit). Yes, the DLL was copied from one machine to the other. We're compiling in Visual Studio 2003 (for our sins).

Comment: @atkins Please provide code showing how the comparison is taking place.  e.g. `bool areCloseEnough() { const float CLOSE_ENOUGH_EPSIOLON = 1e-8; float a = sqrt(foo); float b = pow(bar, baz); return fabs(a - b) < CLOSE_ENOUGH_EPSILON; }`

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler The comparison is made with a simple 'a < b'. For the same inputs (from which a and b are derived via some floating-point operations) and the same compiled binary this evaluates to false on one machine and true on another.

Comment: @atkins Need more code than just `a < b `.  Voting to close.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler I'm sorry, but that is the _only_ relevant code. My question is not about the particulars of the code, but about how I can get different results from floating point operations from the same compiled binary when executed on different machines.

Comment: I notice this question has received a few 'off topic' votes - can anyone suggest a more appropriate SE site for it? Super User?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same DLL on 2 different computers even though both are running Windows XP could conceivably produce the different results you're seeing. These are the reasons that occur to me:

- They could use different version of the C++ runtime (since that is likely dynamically linked) or of other system dlls.
- I don't know how likely this is but I would believe that the floating point operations on different CPUs could produce different enough results for 2 series of calculations of `a` and `b` such that `a < b == true` on one machine and `a < b == false` on another.

What I've used in the past to find out what DLLs are being used by an application is [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: Thanks, Mike - indeed, your first reason seemed the most likely to me. Do you have any idea how I could determine that categorically (i.e. how can I check what C++ runtime is being linked to in a particular execution environment)?

Comment: I edited the answer to include a link to the depends (dependency walker) tool I've used in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there can be differences in floating point implementations that are significant enough to cause equality comparisons to fail.

You can attribute it to failure to implement the IEEE standards properly, but I can see situations where, for example, a different number of guard digits might be used in different implementations, and so the round-off errors might be different.  It should be noted, however that the IEEE standards are rather strict.

Comparisons between floating point numbers should never use exact equality.  Favor an approach where you can test for numbers being within a small range of error, rather than exact equality.

**Further Reading**
[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf)

Comment: I think it is perfectly reasonable to compare floating point numbers for equality in some situations. `a = b/c+d; a1 = b/c+d;` had better result in `a == a1', in other words the exact same sequence of operations on the exact same values had better produce the exact same result. (not across compilers or machines only in the same flow of execution on a single machine).

Comment: I guess my question is: in the situation I describe (i.e. the exact same DLL deployed on different machines) is it possible that I am using different floating point implementations in those two environments. It's more a question about Microsoft DLLs than floating-point arithmetic per se.

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2003, MS C++ compiler introduced a new model for floating-point optimization. It provides you with 3 compiler options: fp:fast; fp:precise; fp:struct.

Under the fp:strict mode, the compiler never performs any optimizations that perturb the accuracy of floating-point computations, so if you want accuracy over speed, you should use this one.  The default one is fp:precise. You can change in the project properties->C++->Code generation.

Please read this: [Microsoft Visual C++ Floating-Point Optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289157%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#floapoint_topic4)

Comment: This is probably the most likely reason.

Comment: I can't check at the moment which mode we have this set to, but I'm not sure I see how this could explain my getting different results from the same compiled binary when executed on different machines?